# Adding root folder outside of public to hosting Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have the following structure (to handle different theming) using different websites on Firebase.

```
/src
/theme-1/index.html
/theme-2/index.html
```

All the "juice" is within `src` and the file `index.html` is the same for both `theme-1` and `theme-2` with exception of the line where I refer to the `.css` file, where I use actually a different on.

For the moment, I only configured one target but I will add more in my `firebase.json`:

{
    "hosting": {

```
    "target": "theme-1",
    "public": "theme-1",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {"source": "**","destination": "/theme-1/index.html"}
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "headers": [ {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [ {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=60"
        } ]
     } ]

}
```

}

I then configure my target using the cmd commands to point to my firebase site:

```
firebase target:apply hosting theme-1 theme-1
```

and subsequently deploy the website:

```
firebase deploy
```

However, when I visit the page (despite it working locally), it seems not to be able to find the root folder /src (404 error).

How can I also include the folder /src in my deployment such that it works in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the directory specified by `public` is deployed to Firebase. The name is slightly misleading because there are no "private" files/directories.

So you have to do `"public": "src"` (or `"public": "."` if you want to deploy the `theme` directories as well), and adjust the other properties accordingly.